# Passing props with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This may seem a silly and obvious question, but I can't seem to get my props to work...

Can anybody tell me why I can't get a console.log of my passed props?

Of course, I will be wanting to do more complicated functions later on, but I thought I would try to get the basics figured out first WITHOUT JUST COPYING A YOUTUBE TUTORIAL

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import List from './Components/list';
import Input from './Components/input';

const tasks = [
  { name: 'task1', isComplete: false },
  { name: 'task2', isComplete: true },
  { name: 'task3', isComplete: false },
]

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      error: null
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <List taskList={this.state.tasks}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**list.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ListBody from './ListComponents/list-body';
import ListHeader from './ListComponents/list-header';

class List extends React.Component {

  clickMe() {
    var passed = this.props.taskList
    console.log(passed);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.clickMe}>List Button</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default List;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have the state with tasks so you're passing an undefined prop.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      tasks
    }
  }
```

Note that tasks is a [shorthand](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand) for "tasks: tasks".

You can check this for yourself if you do `console.log(this.state.tasks)` on your render function.

Comment: While your code is correct, I would suggest either adding an explanation of why it's just `tasks` and not `tasks: tasks` like in `error` above it - or just do `tasks: tasks`. More newbie friendly :)

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the advice!
I also spotted that I had been a burke and not put "()" at the end of my method call in the List.js file...

Comment: Agree. Will update the post!. @physicsboy Glad I could help. If you need anything just post it and we'll help you if posible ;)

Comment: I have a conundrum for you... I'm trying to pass props down the chain and output the list (I'm doing a simple CRUD list of tasks), but I can't seem to get the lodash map to work. You're more than welcome to suggest something better also. See my codeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/r7plvrznop

Comment: @physicsboy You should make another post since using comments to resolve problems isn't right. In any case, I fixed that one for you. You're passing down the prop with another name (tasks != taskList). You don't need lodash to map that function you can use plain javascript map function for it. Here's the code fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/r2r52zv4n

Comment: in addition to not being in state -> `clickMe` also does not have the proper context to access props, you either need to `bind` it to `this` in the constructor or define it as an arrow function `clickMe = () => {...`

Comment: @Rodius - Apologies, I just thought I might lose you if I'd started a new question :-P
Thank you for the help. I thought I was missing something with passing all of the props through. It's making more sense now.

Comment: @EricHasselbring - Id spotted that a little bit earlier, but thanks for pointing out my n00b mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have any value set for taskList in state.this.state.task is undefined. set it some thing and you will be able to see that